# Как добавить в выпадающий список выбираемые элементы PyQt5

Tags: python, pyqt5, qcombobox

Я хочу добавить в выпадающий список выбор элементов из списка, который парсится в процессе выполнения программы.
Я сделал графический интерфейс с помощью Qt Designer, но без добавления комбобоксов.
Подгрузил его с помощью:

```
app = QtWidgets.QApplication([])
ui = uic.loadUi('hwmon.ui')
...
ui.show()
app.exec()
```

Поиски в интернете увенчались только созданием подкласса, который в моем случае перекрывает выполнение интерфейса и показывает один комбобокс, пропуская остальной интерфейс, который хранится в .ui файле.

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtWidgets
from PyQt5.QtGui import QFont
import sys


# subclass
class CheckableComboBox(QtWidgets.QComboBox):
    # once there is a checkState set, it is rendered
    # here we assume default Unchecked
    def addItem(self, item):
        super(CheckableComboBox, self).addItem(item)
        item = self.model().item(self.count() - 1, 0)
        item.setFlags(QtCore.Qt.ItemIsUserCheckable | QtCore.Qt.ItemIsEnabled)
        item.setCheckState(QtCore.Qt.Unchecked)

    def itemChecked(self, index):
        item = self.model().item(i, 0)
        return item.checkState() == QtCore.Qt.Checked


# the basic main()
app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
dialog = QtWidgets.QMainWindow()
dialog.setGeometry(450, 450, 450, 450)
mainWidget = QtWidgets.QWidget()
dialog.setCentralWidget(mainWidget)
ComboBox = CheckableComboBox(mainWidget)
ComboBox.setGeometry(20, 210, 181, 26)
font = QFont('Century Gothic', 11)
ComboBox.setFont(font)

dialog.show()
sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Мне нужно как-то поместить в ui файл этот подкласс, или как-то запускать их вместе.
Работать с полноценными классами не мой вариант.

Comment: вы забыли опубликовать модуль `hwmon.ui`

Comment: Файл .ui генерируется в программе qt designer.
В данном случае он может быть любым.
Мне лишь важно, чтобы работал подкласс и .ui файл в одном окне.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Не имею под рукой PyQt5, но насколько я помню надо делать так:

(лучше) Создайте для вашего `CheckableComboBox` отдельный файл `CheckableComboBox.py` и перенесите туда исходный код вашего комбо.

Далее, запустите `QtDesigner` и поместите в нужное место стандартный QComboBox, затем нажмите на нем `ПКМ` и в выпадающем меню, выберите пункт `"Преобразовать в..."`.

В открывшемся диалоге введите следующее:

- В поле `Имя преобразованного класса`: `CheckableComboBox`
- В поле `Заголовочный файл`: - `CheckableComboBox.py` (по умолчанию будет `.h` в конце, надо чтобы было `.py`)
- Нажмите кнопку `"Добавить"`

Далее перейдите в файл, в котором вы загружаете ui и импортируйте в него `CheckableComboBox`

```
# Если CheckableComboBox.py на одном уровне с main.py, или как там у вас называется
# файл с точкой входа, то так
from CheckableComboBox import CheckableComboBox
```

Теперь перед загрузкой `.ui` надо сделать следующий вызов:

```
sys.modules['CheckableComboBox'] = CheckableComboBox
ui = uic.loadUi(...)
```

Если ничего не забыл, то должно подхватиться. Проверяйте